# Copy div's append showing code how to fix it

Tags: javascript, html

I using code to copy div's content using the code below :

```
 <textarea cols="100" rows="10" id="output"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" onClick="javascript:copyText();" value="Copy">

 function copyText(){
 var output = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("output").value = output;
 }
```

The problem is my div's in in list from append function. when i click copy the result will show the code. I want exact value showing in div's.

[The full code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/technique13/KdAxW/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change innerHtml to InnerText property

```
var output = document.getElementById("container").innerText;
```

InnerHtml returns the html content of the element whereas innerText return the text(value)

See the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdAxW/4/)